# Subdivision Surface modifier is not visible in rendered shading mode

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

*Subdivision Surface modifier* is not worked in render view when render is set to 6 and view is set to 0. What is meant by the 'view' and 'render' options here?

Comment: Your *Subdivision Surface* modifier is disabled

Answer (score 4):

You should put more than 0 in the View parameter of your modifier, typically 2. View is for the Object or Rendered mode of the 3D view, Render is for a definitive render when you click the Render button in the Render menu of the Properties (6 is a lot though).

Answer (score 2):

Rendered viewing mode, while it technically is rendering out your scene, still qualifies as a viewport shading mode. Therefore, your settings for what will appear in the viewport will affect this shading mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had solved this problem later when i am click render button in properties editor[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really solve your problem, you've just launched a real Render, so it took account of the ratio you've chosen for Render, which is 6... If you want to see the effect of your modifier when you're working on your object in Object or Rendered mode you have to increase the Subsurf > Subdivisions > View from 0 to 2 for example.

Comment: The Rendered mode is a preview mode made to have a quick preview of the render, not a real Render, you can set the quality of both the Render and the Rendered mode in Render > Sampling > Samples > Render & Preview. Of course you can increase the Preview ratio up to the Render ratio, but it will slow down your preview. I guess you make a little confusion between Render and Rendered mode.